# Azure cache failing with multiple concurrent requests

Tags: caching, azure

Everything with my co-located cache works fine as long as there is one request at a time. But when I hit my service with several concurrent requests, my cache doesn't seem to work.

Preliminary analysis led me to this - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-service/

Apparently, I would have to use `maxConnectionsToServer` to allow multiple concurrent connections to cache. But the document also talks about a `useLegacyProtocol` parameter which has to be set to false to enable connection pooling.

I have the following questions:

1. My service would be getting a few hundred concurrent requests. Would this be a
   good setting for such a scenario:

   > <dataCacheClient name="default" maxConnectionsToServer="100"
   >   useLegacyProtocol="false">

   This is my understanding of the behavior I would get with this configuration - Each time a request comes in, an attempt would be made to retrieve a connection from the pool. If there is no available connection, a new connection would be created if there are less than 100 connections currently, else the request would fail. Please confirm if this is correct.
2. The above documentation says that one connection would be used per instance of DataCacheFactory. I have a cache manager class which manages all interactions with cache. This is a singleton class. It creates a DataCacheFactory object and uses it to get a handle to the cache during its instantiation. My service would have 2 instances. Looks like I would need only 2 connections to server. Is this correct? Do I even need connection pooling?
3. What is the maximum value maxConnectionsToServer can accept and what would be an ideal value for the given scenario?
4. I also see a boolean paramater named "ConnectionPool". This looks complementary to "useLegacyProtocol". Is this not redundant? How is setting useLegacyProtocol="false" different from connectionPool="true"? I am confused as to whether or not and how to use this parameter.
5. Are `maxConnectionsToServer` and `ConnectionPool` parameters related in any way? What does it mean when I have maxConnectionsToServer set to 5 and ConnectionPool=true?

Comment: Please explain how the co-located cache doesn't seem to work? We are using co-located and don't seem to have issues with multiple concurrent calls